# Symfony 1.4 forms using Propel Object '<class here>' not Found

Tags: php, forms, widget, symfony-1.4, propel

From this page:

```
main_dev.php/player/new
```

to (when I click submit):

```
main_dev.php/player/edit/player_id/(no id)
```

if I put an id here it displays fine.

When I click the submit button (somehow it saves) but displays this:

> 404 | Not Found | sfError404Exception
>
> Object Player does not exist().

this is my baseform:

```
$this->setWidgets(array(
  'player_id'      => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(), //primary key auto increment()
  'player_name'    => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
  'player_gold'    => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
  'chara_id'       => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
  'open_social_id' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(), 
));
```

im suspecting that the issue here is that player_id is not displayed and is auto increment. that means that when i submit the form player_id is left blank and since symfony cannot find where to get the id for the reference to display a record it goes 404, is there any workaround in this?

and my action.class is left from the default(instance when i generated it) so i think is not an issue

heres what the code for saving the form:

```
    protected function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)
  {
    $form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()), $request->getFiles($form->getName()));
    if ($form->isValid())
    {
      $Player = $form->save();
      $this->redirect('player/edit?player_id='.$Player->getPlayerId());
    }
  }
```

and ofcourse for the new page controller:

```
public function executeNew(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    $this->form = new PlayerForm();
}
```

Comment: can you show the code which saves the player information

Comment: @ Rohit Subedi when you click submit it actually saves to the database, but the problem is showing the information saved; btw person_id is primary key and is auto incremented by the database so the user has no need to fill them(i set it to form hidden), and so i think it will not exist in the post method either.

Answer (score 0):

If the POST request saves a new Player object (in the database), it is not your BasePlayerForm.class, nor the submit url.

If your routing works when manually entered, and not when called within the action class, then your routing.yml is probably not the problem.

If you have not over-written the `configure()` of the BasePlayerForm.class.php (in PlayerForm.class.php, or anywhere else), then it is not in your lib/form/ classes.

Either this answer is useless (sorry) or you do not actually mean that the action "saves" the object to the database - in which case, check the submit url/request from the newSuccess template; also verify your routing:

Your newSuccess.php form tag action should POST to main_dev.php/player:
`<form method="post" action="/main_dev.php/player">` 
[And pass the id rendered in html as `<input type="hidden" name="player[player_id]" id="player_id" />`.]
Lastly, the edit routing in the url will normally match `player/:player_id/edit` - check if you actually have an auto-created "id" column in your schema/database in addition to the "player_id" which might really be what is causing this.

Comment: okay player_id = auto increment/primary key(this will not be filled by the user which means it will be empty when the user presses submit).

Comment: @user2064173 Sounds like you have 2 pk's in the same table ("person_id is primary key..." and "player_id = auto increment/primary key"). That may be an issue. A hidden pk field is not an issue and is passed in POST and handled by the db. Didn't see person_id anywhere in your code.

Comment: i didn't have any person_id column in my db, though i think i probably have a hint, as you have said A hidden pk field was not an issue.